# How to get a caller principal in my backing bean?

Tags: java, jsf

This is my backing bean (deployed to GlassFish):

```
@ManagedBean
@DeclareRoles({ "USER" })
@RolesAllowed("USER")
public class MyBean {
  public MyBean() {}
  public final String getId() {
    Principal p = .. // how and where?
    return p.getName();
  }
}
```

How and where I can get `java.security.Principal` object to understand who is logged in now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain it by [`ExternalContext#getUserPrincipal()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29).

```
Principal principal = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();
```

Comment: I am getting nullpointer exception on this code. why is that?

Comment: @victorio: all possible causes of an exception are usually already listed in exception's own javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html Among others, when you attempt to call an instance method on a `null` reference. If you still stucks, just press "Ask Question" and post a good SSCCE. My best guess would be that you attempted to grab the `FacesContext` at the wrong moment (i.e. when it isn't been created yet), like in a servlet filter.

Comment: thank you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772780/why-does-my-facescontext-getcurrentinstance-getexternalcontext-getuserprinci