# Why does my FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal() code runs to NullPointer?

Tags: jsf, ejb, weblogic, principal, facescontext

I have a stateless bean which has a method, where I want to get the current/logged user.
My code to get it:

```
Principal p1 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();
```

But I am getting nullpointer exception on this. Why is that?

Or is there any other way to get the logged user? 
I am using weblogic.

Answer (score 3):

You're not supposed to grab the `FacesContext` in an EJB. Even more, your EJBs should be completely free from any JSF dependencies. In other words, you should not have any code imported from `javax.faces.*` package inside your EJBs. Your EJBs should be designed that way that they are reusable across all different front-ends you can think of such as JSF, JAX-RS, Struts, Spring-MVC and even "plain vanilla" Servlets.

If you're using container managed security or a security framework like Apache Shiro, then you're supposed to use the API-provided facilities for that. In case of "plain vanilla" container managed security (JAAS via `web.xml` and so on), you're supposed to obtain it form [`SessionContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/SessionContext.html) (which is rightfully from `javax.ejb` package) which can be injected as `@Resource`.

```
@Resource
private SessionContext context;

public void doSomething() {
    Principal principal = context.getCallerPrincipal();
    // ...
}
```

An alternative would be to pass the JPA entity representation of the logged-in user as method argument.

Comment: I tried your code too, but I am getting the `<anonymus>` username. :/

Comment: Are you using container managed security or a 3rd party API like Shiro?

Comment: Wait, this appears to be a Weblogic specific issue: https://www.google.com/search?q=weblogic+sessioncontext+getcallerprincipal+anonymous Have you configured the `weblogic-ejb-jar` as shown in this blog? http://biemond.blogspot.com/2009/12/ejb-session-bean-security-in-weblogic.html

Answer (score -1):

verify the import of the following library:

```
javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
```

Try again

Comment: This makes totally no sense. Especially without any explanation